# C# - Pixel Color Count in PictureBox with Graphics

Tags: c#, graphics, bitmap, picturebox

Good morning StackOverflow!

I have a small project that generates some G Code, with a small visualizer to see what the G Code will recreate on the machine.

I am trying to count all the pixels in my PictureBox to calculate a percentage of the red pixels in the PictureBox.

While I have a good idea how to calculate the Pixels by themselves, I cannot get what my PictureBox is showing.

```
Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(PB_Graph.Width, PB_Graph.Height, graphics);
        int redColor = 0;
        for (int x = 0; x < bmp.Width; x++)
        {
            for (int y = 0; y < bmp.Height; y++)
            {
                Color color = bmp.GetPixel(x, y);

                if (color.ToArgb() == Color.Red.ToArgb())
                    redColor++;
            }
        }
        Double Coverage = redColor * 100 / (PB_Graph.Width * PB_Graph.Height);
```

I created a Graphics to go with it, but the Graphic is initialized globally, since many of my functions write to it.

```
Graphics graphics;
    public GCodeRandomizer()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        graphics = PB_Graph.CreateGraphics();
        graphics.ScaleTransform(1.0F, -1.0F);
        graphics.TranslateTransform(0.0F, -(float)PB_Graph.Height);
        graphics.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;
    }
```

Exemple of a DrawLine:

```
            graphics.DrawLine(new Pen(Color.Red), (float)((TempX - XBase) * PB_Graph.Width / Double.Parse(TBX_BufferZone_Width.Text)), (float)((TempY - YBase - 4) * PB_Graph.Height / Double.Parse(TBX_BufferZone_Height.Text)), (float)((X - XBase) * PB_Graph.Width / Double.Parse(TBX_BufferZone_Width.Text)), (float)((Y - YBase - 4) * PB_Graph.Height / Double.Parse(TBX_BufferZone_Height.Text)));
```

What my program looks like:
[MyProject](https://i.stack.imgur.com/325B7.png)

So, all I need is a way to convert my Graphics to a Bitmap, because I know this is what is needed to count my pixels.
My problem is: When I do something like `Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(PB_Graph.Width, PB_Graph.Height, graphics);`, it only shows a blank image without my drawings.

Thanks!

Comment: The Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(... line only creates a new Bitmap with the dpi of the passed Graphics. You need to use the Graphics to write to an Image, then can pass that Image to the Bitmap constructor.

Comment: There is no way to get a bitmap from a graphics object, since the graphics object preforms one way operations - draw to the device context. Maybe a better option in this case would be to create an empty image with the control's size and then use the [DrawToBitmap](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.drawtobitmap(v=vs.110).aspx) method of the control.

Comment: Well, I changed my method and draw directly onto a bitmap instead of drawing on my PictureBox. When the graph is done I put it as an Image on my PictureBox. It loses its animated charm, but it fixes this problem + the drawings no longer disappears when you put a window over it. Thanks for the quick replies guys.

Comment: The `Graphics` object does not __contain__ any graphics; it is a **tool** that lets you draw onto a related bitmap, including a control's surface.  - _`graphics = PB_Graph.CreateGraphics();`_ This is the root of all evil. Either draw __into__ a `Bitmap` or __onto__ a Control. For the first use `(Graphics G = GraphicsFromImage(bmp))`for the latter `e.Graphics` in the `Paint` event. To access the pixels in the latter case use `DrawToBitmap`..!

Comment: Yes I am currently using `bmp = new Bitmap(PB_Graph.Width, PB_Graph.Height); graphics = Graphics.FromImage(bmp);` . It works fine! :) I lost the animated touch (I liked seeing all the lines getting drawn), but I guess I can't have everything I wanted in that scenario haha. Thanks for all the help.

Comment: Maybe you can draw it twice, once to the screen and once to the bitmap...